# How to update mediaItem from firestore stream when app in background

Tags: flutter, audio-service

Currently, when the app is in the foreground it updates the player with the current playing media item from a firebase stream. The player is updated using the method below in the `BaseAudioHandler`:

```
@override
Future<void> updateMediaItem(MediaItem mediaItem) {
  this.mediaItem.add(mediaItem);
  return Future<void>.value();
}
```

When the app is in the background, the Firestore stream is paused so the currently playing mediaItem on the notification screen isn't getting updated.

Any hints on updating the currently playing media from an external stream like firestore?

Comment: try this https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens

Comment: @ManishDayma To my understanding, this requires the app user to give permission for push notifications. I can see this easily being turned off, then making the song information not updated and look like a bug.